# Algorithms - Semi definite programming

Tags: algorithm

Let `G=({1,...,n},E)` be a graph with two edge weight functions ֿ`αe ≤ βe`, `e ∈ E`.

I want to know whether there exist points `p1 ,..., pn ∈ Rn`, such that `α{i,j} ≤ ||pi−pj||^2 ≤ β{i,j}`, for all `{i,j} ∈ E`.

How can I show that this decision problem can be formulated as a semidefinite program?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.  Try cs.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Hint:  Use a Gram matrix instead of squared distances between points.  Your constraints become linear inequalities.